How to fix weight painting
When I try to weight paint this entire head model to a bone it works and correctly paints everything
but when I select the jaw bone (as seen on the picture) and weight paint it, it sort of overrides the head weight paint and subtracts
Im on version 4.1


Vertices cant have total weights-to-bones with a sum greater than 1. I think what you want to do is weight paint the mouth to parent the mouth verts to the mouth/tongue bones and then make sure those bones are parented to the root "head" bone. That way the jaw will be controlled by the "jaw" bone, but since the jaw will be parented to the head they will also follow the head whenever it moves.

Deactivate the Auto Normalize option, this way a vertex can have a sum of weight that exceeds 1:

